# Top 10 collection completion - a monster in-query formula in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

I've got the following tables:

User Basic Data (unique)
`[userid]  [name]  [etc]`

User Collection (one to one)
`[userid]  [game]`

User Recorded Plays (many to many)
`[userid]  [game]  [scenario]  [etc]`

Game Basic Data (unique)
`[game]  [total_scenarios]`

I would like to output a table that shows the collection play completion percentage for  the Top 10 users in descending order of %:

Output Table

```
[userid]  [collection_completion]
   3               95%
   1               81%
  24               68%
  etc              etc
```

In my mind, the calculation sequence for ONE USER is:

1. grab user's total owned scenarios from `User Collection` joined with `Game Basic Data` and `COUNT(gbd.total_scenarios)`
2. grab all recorded plays by `COUNT(DISTINCT scenario)` for that user
3. Divide all recorded plays by total owned scenarios

So that's 2 queries and a little PHP massage at the end. For a list of users sorted by completion percentage things get a little more complicated.

I figure I could grab *all users' collection totals* in one query, and *all users recorded plays* in another, and then do the calcs and sort the final array in PHP, but it seems like overkill to potentially be doing all that for 1000+ users when I only ever want the Top 10.

Is there a wicked monster query in MySQL that could do all that and `LIMIT 10`? Or is sticking with PHP handling the bulk of the work the way to go in this case?

Comment: You could store the percentage somewhere else (e.g. another table) and update it when you make changes to `User Recorded Plays`. Then it would be a simple JOIN... ORDER BY percentage. Is that feasible in your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you require correctly, you can try something like

```
SELECT  userid,
        us.TotalUserscenario / gbd.total_scenarios collection_completion
FROM    (
            SELECT  userid,
                    game,
                    COUNT(scenario) TotalUserscenario
            FROM    UserRecordedPlays urp
            GROUP BY    userid,
                        game
        ) UserScenarios us INNER JOIN
        GameBasicData gbd ON us.game = gbd.game
ORDER BY collection_completion DESC
LIMIT 10
```